# Batch command to change an icon of the currently running window

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

In my working environment I can have up to 10 command prompt windows open, each one set up to work in a different context. Having all of them open, I find myself having to switch between several of them to find the right one that I want to work with.

I am already setting different foreground and background colors of each window based on some criteria, but it would be much more easier to distinguish between them by having a different colored icon in the taskbar. That way, I would not even have to maximize/bring them to focus to find the right one from the get-go.

Is there a way that I can change the taskbar icon of the currently running command prompt window programmatically by executing batch commands in it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "built-in" way to do that, like there is the `color` command from `cmd.exe` to change the colors.

You could either search the internet for some utilitiy, or roll your own, for example in C#, by invoking the `SetConsoleIcon` Win32 API.  Note however, that this API is not officially documented, YMMV.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint SetConsoleIcon(IntPtr iconHandle);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args[0].Equals("--reset", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            SetConsoleIcon(IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        else
        {
            // Use this to load an icon from an icon file instead:
            //   var icon = new Icon(args[0]); // load from .ico file
            // Extract icon from given executable/dll.
            using (var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(args[0]))
            {
                if (icon != null)
                    SetConsoleIcon(icon.Handle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to compile this using `csc.exe setconico.cs` (assuming you named the file `setconico.cs`). This will generate `setconico.exe`, which you can use like this:

Set the current console icon of the console you run this in, to the icon of notepad.exe

```
c:\> setconico.exe c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

You might also be able to write the above code in PowerShell, if you don't want to compile a separate utility.

Comment: Doesn't work in win11.